# Center footer container on Boostrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently working on refining a footer for an example site I'm working through with Bootstrap 4.  I took a footer from one of their marketing examples to play around with, but I'm noticing one key difference: it's left-align instead of centered.  Also, the container the footer is inside of does not take up the entire bottom of the page:

[image]

Here's my HTML code:

```
    <footer class="container text-center  py-5" id="footer">
            <div class="row mx-5 justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-12 col-md">
                    <i class="fas fa-dna footer-dna fa-2x"></i>
                <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2019</small>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>Features</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>Resources</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                        <li><a class="text-muted" href="/newsletter">Sign Up For Email</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>Resources</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Business</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Education</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Government</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Gaming</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 col-md">
                <h5>About</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                  <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </footer>
```

I've played around with the "max-width" property for the container, but that spreads the content out through the entire bottom footer rather than through the center.  What am I missing here?  thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: its already center in my machine, please create snippet that shows your problem

Comment: @NishargShah here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/franchise/pen/MWaoXOp.  I've been able to center it, but not with a color filling the entire bottom container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-width` prevent your full size, so shift that to the child and give child to `margin: auto` so it will be center.

```css
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #951010;
}

#footer .row {
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Footer Pen</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/175e0bfa97.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <footer class="container-fluid text-center py-5" id="footer">
    <div class="row footer-row mx-auto">
      <div class="col-12 col-md">
        <i class="fas fa-dna footer-dna fa-2x"></i>
        <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2019</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md">
        <h5>Features</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md">
        <h5>Resources</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="/newsletter">Sign Up For Email</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md">
        <h5>Resources</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Business</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Government</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Gaming</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md">
        <h5>About</h5>
        <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you for helping drive home that understanding.

Answer (score 0):

add two new proporties `left:0` and `right:0;`

```
#footer {
 max-width: 960px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: That does essentially the same thing as a max-with: 100% property, so thank you for that.  However, I want to the center the content in the middle of that full size container.

Comment: Can you give me the link of your issue please. Right now if I check your code in codepen it working perfectly so give me link of your issue pls

Comment: Sure.  Here's a link to what I see: https://codepen.io/franchise/pen/MWaoXOp.  Here's an example of what I'm looking to create: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/product/.  The spacing between each <UL> is much smaller and all of the content is more focused at the center.

Comment: Well as I can see your have to remove container-fluid and text-center and its not smaller like your example its because it DON'T use bootstrap container class it used custom style...so you have to change width of container like below 
.footer{max-width: 960px;}

Comment: I know what the issue is.  Since I'm trying to make this a sticky footer and have it on the bottom of the page (if the content is too small to fill the page, keep the footer on the bottom rather than having extra whitespace), I'm using {position: aboslute; bottom: 0}.  That's what is causing the higher amount of spacing.  What can be done for that?  I've added it to my codepen linked above.

Comment: added new answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212710/discussion-between-franchise-and-rahul).